Comparing large ints in mysql
I need to know how to query a mysql database to fetch very large ints (48 bytes) within a range. I have set up my table as such:
primary: varbinary(48) primary key
secondary: varbinary(48)
ternary: varbinary(48)
timestamp: bigint

I would need a query like:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONV(primary, 16, 10) <= CONV("some large hex string", 16, 10) and CONV(primary, 16, 10) >= CONV("some large hex string", 16, 10);

Right now, this query just returns all rows regardless of whether primary fits the range or not. How can I change the query to accurately compare the primary value to the large hex strings (or do I need to change my table setup to make it work better)?

Compare right-justified binary values or reversed ones.

@Akina I dont understand what you are suggesting. Can you show me a query text to demonstrate what you mean?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question
